# Exporting a type from another module with all type info

Tags: typescript, module, bunyan

I have a module that contains one export. It's a factory function to create a [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) logger:

```
export default function createLogger(options: LoggerOptions, /*...*/): Logger {
    // returns a bunyan Logger with some extra stuff for our company
}
```

I want to use this module in other applications, and I want to include the type info of the bunyan `Logger` instance, so that we have intellisense for stuff like `logger.info`, `logger.warn`, etc.

So, I exported both my factory function and the bunyan Logger from my index.ts file:

```
import Logger from "bunyan";
import createLogger from "./createLogger";

export {
    createLogger,
    Logger
};
```

However, when I import this in another application, I can see that my IDE thinks logger is of type `any`:

[image: type is any]

Is this because bunyan doesn't export the Logger type? Or because in my application, I only installed my custom package and not bunyan? I would prefer that users of the custom package don't have to install both my package *and* bunyan.

Is there a way to fix this, ie have intellisense of the bunyan logger without having to separately install bunyan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. As bunyan exports a namespace, I had to change my index.ts to:

```
import * as Logger from "bunyan";
import createLogger from "./createLogger";

export {
    createLogger,
    Logger
};
```

Notice how I do `import * as Logger from "bunyan"`, which imports everything from bunyan and calls it "Logger". Now everything works as expected.